# Force.com App Menu, Removing "AppExchange" & "Developer Community"

Tags: page-layout

As an Administrators I am attempting to modify the Apps accessible to profiles via the "Force.com App Menu" - here is the process I am using:

1. Goto Administration Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles ->
2. Choose Profile
3. Profile Overview -> Assigned Profile
4. Edit and choose the apps

Issues is that I am unable to remove "AppExchange" & "Developer Community" - and "Power of Us Hub" from the menu. Guessing these are "required" but looking for confirmation that there's no workaround to get this done; meaning, I get Salesforce wants to build a community, market apps, etc. -- and that's fine for me, but in my opinion, they're just confusing to users that do not need it, an yet another interface element to ingest, recall, and forget.

---

**UPDATE:** Not 100% sure how I did it, but this is what it looks like; note that the "Force.com App Menu" is not present, it should be to the right of "Help & Training" - I'll attempt to figure out how I did it, though possible someone else knows how, or that the way I did it might only work sometimes.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how you actually did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user has only one app there is no dropdown shown to switch apps